# flutterflow infinite starting page at 1 instead of 0

Tags: flutter, flutterflow

I'm trying to use `https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1` API example from their tutorial on using infinity scroll.

Infinity scroll starts at index 0 page, however, page 0 is equitant to page 1, which ends up showing a duplicate list of rows on flutter-flow.

How can I tell infinite scroll to start with page value 1, instead of 0? I have tried setting default values.

The tutorial I have been following:
https://docs.flutterflow.io/widgets-and-components/widgets-ui-elements/layout-elements/listview#infinite-scroll-on-a-list-from-api-call

Comment: I have an opposite problem: can't change from 0 as the starting page to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Hope your query has been resolved by now. However, if it hasn't, here's a suggestion for passing the next page index starting from 1 instead of 0. Instead of directly using the 'next page' variable provided by Flutter, you can write a code expression to receive the default next page parameter as a parameter and return 'default_next_page + 1'

Comment: Where to put this expression in FlutterFlow?

Comment: @abdulrehman-khan, may I know where u added this code in FF to get default_next_page + 1